# UML Modelling Embarcadero c++ builder Tokyo 10.2.3 Class Diagram

Tags: ide, uml, c++builder, class-diagram, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have a problem with the view "Model". I wanted to generate a Class Diagram of my C++ application.

But when I load my view model, there is white, nothing displayed.

In the option -> Modelisation -> Diagram -> General

The support of model is active.

I have use them

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Activating_UML_Modeling_Support_for_Projects

But they doesn't match

I haven't the windows Modeling Support, same at 1 minute on this video for checked my already project :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTpAAz3WkZk&t=4s

Answer (score 1):

I've writing at the french provider they selling them, adn answer that : 
UML Modeling isn't available with C++ Builder, on the Embarcadero IDE only the code writing with language Delphi is supported.

https://www.embarcadero.com/docs/rad-studio-feature-matrix.pdf